# Wildfly 10 + Eclipselink 2.6.4 - @Observes(during = TransactionPhase.AFTER_SUCCESS) - Get stale entity

Tags: eclipselink, wildfly

I have noticed a strange problem on Wildfly 10 that does not occur in weblogic.

In summary, in wildfly, I am experiencing that an `@ApplicationScoped` bean that observers an event  `@Observes(during = TransactionPhase.AFTER_SUCCESS) SomeEvent` event, and that in its observe logic uses an `@EJB` to open up a fresh and small lived transaction context, is getting access a stale entity modified by the original `@Mdb` transaction that published the event.

And this "Single Thread" phenomena can lead to multiple interesting exceptions.

Type of error 1: Optimistic lock exception:
If your `AFTER_SUCCESS` observer wants to run itself a short transaction that modifies the entity of the primary transaction that published the event.

Well - on the first try you get an optimistic locking exception.
You get it because even though the MDB run its transaction on Thread1, and your serial observer is observing after success on Thread 1.
You have the problem that the MDB successfully committed the changes to the DB if you go check for those, but you observer is loading the entity from the Entity Manager as if it was stale, in the state as before the Mdb run.
So the `@versioninfo` is just stale and Eclipselink thinks you have an optimistic lock exception.
If you allow the optimistic lock exception to happen and retry a second time to run the transaction on the same Thread1, you overcome the problem and manage to get your changes through.
This is sloppy and ugly but it works.

The second type of problem is more serious.
If your `@bserver` on success does a Read only transaction, that nothing blows up and you are not given any indication that you are using stale data.
This is bad, really really bad.

So here I try in my observer doing something like.

```
MyEntity entity = em.fetchById(primaryKeyOfEntity);
String staleValue = entity.getFieldModifiedByMdbTransaction();
em.refreh(rentity);
String secondTryToGetTheValue = entity.getFieldModifiedByMdbTransaction();
// now the value is no longer stale it is perfect. It is what the MDB that published the event committed.
```

Using the same eclipselink version on weblogic 12.2.1.2 the pattern of `@Observing ON_SUCCESS` is not returning any stale data. 
The changes done on the first Mdb transaction are well published to the `ON_SUCCESS` transaction that runs after it on the same thread.

Is anyone aware of this?
Is there a way to tell the entity manager that it should use the server session cache and not the local cache?
Could it be that EclipselInk is only moving the Unit Of Work cache of modified entities to the server cache after the Event ON_SUCCESS is handled and not on the `onCommit()`? Meaning, the server session cache is holding stale entities until the `ON_SUCCESS` has finished? - This should not be. When the commit is fired to the DB and before the `ON_SUCCESS` gets called, the Unit of work cache must be published to session cache.

However, the `ON_SUCCESS` is literally on a `@TransactionAttribute(RequriesNew)`, when it starts it should have an empty unit of work.

In addition, I have attempt to `entitManager.clear()`, it has not effect.
The only thing that works in brining out a non stale entity is the `em.refresh()`.
And an `em.refresh()` to me always smells like sloppy code.

Anyone else has experienced the same problem on wildfly?
Any magical eclipselink persistence unit property to work around this without killing performance?

Comment: Correlated post: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/195775

Comment: A sample application exists for this issue now: https://github.com/99sono/wildfly10-observe-on-success-stale-entity